# How to implement counter game with state in cardano plutus? (the 10th player can pick reward)

Tags: cardano, plutus

I want to make a simple stateful game in cardano using plutus language (to check what is possible in cardano, and what is not)

The **rules** are the following:

- contract creator deploys smart contract and locks some ADA
- games call the smart contract
- the 10th unique gamer unlocks ADA and can pick up the reward

---

This is trivial to implement in etherium or tezos for example - you just:

- the store has type `array[address]`
- when gamer calls the smart contract you just check that address is not in the array yet AND append new address to the store
- IF `store.length >= 10` THEN caller can collect the reward

---

But how to implement this game in plutus?

What will be the type of:

- data script
- redeemer script
- validator script (it's a function, sorry)
  ??

---

Update

Created similar question, but more realistic [How to implement the voting smart contract in cardano Plutus language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59006158/how-to-implement-the-voting-smart-contract-in-cardano-plutus-language)

Comment: Don't think that the state like this is allowed cardano. I have a feeling that gamer will have to call the contract with the list of proofs that the contract was indeed called by 9 other gamers. BUT how to show proof that these other transactions were indeed accepted by system?

Comment: Have you read Plutus's Book ? I'm learning Haskell and project to read this book to learn Plutus.

https://leanpub.com/plutus-smart-contracts

Comment: @regisg yes, I have read it, but still can't map examples from this book onto this example